# Running Google Docs Add On Drive permissions

Tags: google-apps-script, gsuite-addons

I have tried to create my first google docs add-on.

When I had run the script within a google doc, it worked just fine.  However, when I am publishing the add-on and then installed it, it does not work.  The error message is :

Exception: We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again

I have determined that the line of code which causes the issue is the last one here:

```
  var currentDocumentName = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getName();
  var currentDocumentID = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getId();
  var currentfile = DriveApp.getFileById(currentDocumentID);
```

So it would appear that using the DriveApp cannot run for some reason.

I know this is the line with error for two reasons.  The error message in the google console log says it is this line number.  Also, when I put in some logging messages, the messages end where this line is executed.  I have given the Google drive API permission in the project.

Does anyone know why this error could occur?

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a [bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/159361834). You can click on the star next to the issue number to receive updates and to give more priority to the bug.

As a workaround, try with the [Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get) instead (which is different from DriveApp):

`var file = Drive.Files.get("fileId");`

Comment: may be due to this ? https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/guides/editor-best-practices#_avoid_relying_too_much_on_libraries

Comment: It does seem like the bug you mentioned sounds very much like what is happening. I have starred it. One thing I have noted also, is that I removed the add-on from my organisations library.  I then tried the code again within the document and it did not work still.  So it may relate to the script being converted into a Standard Cloud Platform  project?

Comment: Yes, it could be related. To confirm it, try the same code with a different project, without publishing it as an addon.